# Could this automaton be powered with low-tech means?

Tags: technology, energy, robots

The automaton is a human-sized machine made primarily of wood, clay, cork, wax, and plant cord. It is designed to move around and use tools, and has roughly the same physical abilities as a human. It is controlled and moved by fluid logic and mechanical systems

The power source/store should provide enough power to move it for at least a day, without damaging any of the materials. It has to stay onboard the automaton. This power source shouldn't use any metals, electric components, or fossil fuels, and ideally would only use the materials listed above

Is there a power source/store that fits these criteria?

Comment: An actual human has enough power reserves on board to move and work autonomously for more than a day. The power source does not use any metals, electric components(*) or fossil fuels. So that in principle, yes, it is obviously possible. On the other hand, a non-living robot on the other hand cannot be made with current or near-future technology while obeying the restrictions; also very obviously. What is the purpose of this question? (Note: some very low-power electric currents are produced as a side effect of how the human fabric operates.)

Comment: @AlexP _On the other hand, a non-living robot on the other hand cannot be made with current or near-future technology while obeying the restrictions; also very obviously_ Why? I don't see how this is obvious

Comment: It is obvious because the only even remotely sufficiently dense energy storage devices are (1) some sort of fuel, (2) some sort of battery, or (3) some sort of flywheel. The fuel is out because it would need either an engine or a fuel cell in which to burn; the battery is out because electric; the flywheel is out because the only reasonable way to use its energy is to spin an electric generator -- and a flywheel which could store about 1 kWh of energy is waaaay beyond low-tech anyway.

Comment: @AlexP Why specifically is an engine impossible with these constraints?

Comment: An Otto engine needs an electric subsystem to generate the sparks. A Diesel engine needs high pressure.

Comment: -1 for failing to [examine historical automatons](https://www.history.com/news/7-early-robots-and-automatons) and the many ways they were powered.

Comment: @JBH Neither that link nor any other research shows a method of power that meets the criteria in the question

Comment: As an adjunct to my answer, while I've on rare occasions disagreed with some specific @AlexP has said, I've never found him to be intrinsically wrong. He's one of the most valuable resources on this Stack. When he says something is impossible, that's 99.99% bankable. Rather than arguing with him you should be wondering what you should change about your world or what you're willing to handwave to simply move forward. BTW, compressed air meets your criteria with a large and well constrained bladder - and a bit of suspension-of-disbelief. You did not tag your Q [tag:science-based].

Comment: Are you asking just for a power source (thing that gives energy to the system), or a power AND processing source (thing that gives both energy and the 'intelligence' to the system)?

Comment: Technically renewables like ethanol are NOT fossil fuels, but I suspect you don't want to use them. If they ARE okay, let me know.

Comment: All I can come up with is a 22nd century ceramic gas turbine engine wrapped in asbestos (a natural material) powered by something like ethanol. NOT manufacturable by low tech or practical to make with current tech, but at least theoretically fits the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

As @AlexP clearly stated, humanity at its current level of technology cannot replicate the living system common to all mammals that could achieve your requirements within the materials limitations you demand and no other solution can without access to metal or, at the very least, tempered glass.

That's obvious to anyone with a college-level science education.

*Why you worry about this is a wonder. There's a reason why nearly every scifi writer in history has avoided explaining how their magical machines are powered. Fictional technical manuals abound with rooms labeled "magic happens here" in wondrous technobabble. Humanity's imagination for what it could do with unconstrained power is breathtaking. It's imagination for how to achieve that power is lousy. But more to the point — anyone who could reasonably answer this question wouldn't answer it. They'd be running to the patent office preparatory to making billions of dollars.*

Answer (score 4):

**Child**

[image: child kayak]

https://www.fyneboatkits.co.uk/plans/kayaks/wood-duckling/

The depicted wooden vehicle is powered by the child inside it.  Your wooden automaton is also powered by a child inside it.  The child powers it all day.  This child is in good shape and has worked up to powering the thing all day.  The child has food and water on board.  Because of the OP the child must stay on board all day but has a bucket to use for passing wastes.

The child might also control the automaton, or might just provide the motive force with a bicycle pedal type arrangement.

Human power was used before any other sort of power.  It is still a good low tech way to power a thing.

Comment: +1 for a clever solution. But I'd like to point out the OP's requirement, "and has roughly the same physical abilities as a human." A child's strength might be inadequate to meet that requirement as the automaton must present itself as an adult to fit the child inside (unless we allow the automaton to move very slowly, allowing for power-multiplying pulleys). But at least the automaton will defecate like a real human.

Comment: @JBH - I meant only for the child to be providing motive force.  It might be using levers and pulleys as you suggest.  But it could be winding springs, raising counterweights or other ways to store energy compatible with the limitations in the OP.  I could not think of a purely mechanical way to store as much energy as OP requires so energy will be stored as a biological engine.